# AWS: How to configure Cloudfront for Custom Domain Names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

**My setup:**

**API Gateway** - 10 APIs (api1, api2,...), all mapped to one custom domain name (api.xxx.com)

**Route53** - api.xxx.com pointed to my Cloudfront distribution

**Cloudfront** - distribution created, api.xxx.com set as a CNAME

**What I need to know** - I would like to set Origin of this Cloudfront to this custom domain name, so I can call APIs like *api.xxx.com/api1/endpoint*, *api.xxx.com/api2/endpoint*. But how? I used API Gateway Name of my api.xxx.com Custom Domain name (xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com) for default behavior Origin name and assumed that requests to all 10 APIs will be routed correctly, but it´s not happening,

**What works:** I created Origin name using the Invoke Url of api1 and assigned it to the Default behavior. So now, when I call "https://api.xxx.com/endpoint", api1 gets called. That makes sense, but the problem is - **I need the path to the API to be the part of the URL, such as "https://api.xxx.com/api1/endpoint" so I can differentiate between them.**

**What doesn't work:** But I need several APIs set in the distribution so I can call them like "https://api.xxx.com/api1/endpoint" and so on. And if I use Invoke URL as the Origin name for the API, I cannot attach this API name also to the URL, that returns 403. I was hoping that if I used "API Gateway domain name" of "Custom Domain Names" (after all, it has a format of xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com), I could then use APIs in the URL, but that doesn't work. I cannot even use this "API Gateway domain name" to call individual apis through Postman. Could someone advise me on how to do it? How can I configure Cloudfront so it can call various APIs and use their routes in URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution, described in more detail in this discussion thread. My problem was that I was trying to use link to custom domain name (xxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com) directly from Cloudfront, but I should have used "nice", readable address as Origin name and do the redirect in Route53

Working setup:

1. In API Gateway, Custom Domain Name regional-api.xxx.com is created, endpoint type Regional (xxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com).
2. In Route53, A and AAAA records map regional-api.xxx.com to the Regional endpoint target domain name.
3. Cloudfront distribution created that uses regional-api.xxx.com as the Origin Domain Name and api.xxx.com as a CNAME.
4. In Route53, A and AAAA records map api.xxx.com to the Domain name of a newly created CF distribution.

Answer (score 0):

My setup is a bit different then yours but it seems we want to accomplish the same goal.

I have four S3 buckets which I serve through cloudfront.
One bucket is the root website; 3 other buckets contain 3 different admin panels

For each s3 bucket I created an seperate origin; I believe you should create an origin for each seperate api.

I added for each origin group two path patterns; I believe for your api you can have one pattern per api. A path pattern could look like /api1/* which points to the origin of api1

Not sure if you tried adding origins for all your api's.

Comment: Hello, havent tried to do it for all since for now, even one api doesn´t work. I added pattern for /api1/* but it is for some reason ignored, the only one that works is Default one. So the request to "https://api.xxx.com/endpoint" works, but the one to  "https://api.xxx.com/api1/endpoint" doesnt...

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious here: everything after the pattern part so /api1/* will be added after your origin. So cloudfront.net/api1/endpoint will become xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/endpoint

Comment: Actually, that´s what I didnt realize - Invoke URL of my api already "contains" it, so when I added another /api1/ to the url, the link became invalid. That´s also why worked only my default path, since it was targeting endpoints directly, without "/api1/" in-between. Now just to find out how to be able to call api and use its name as part of the path, since I need to assign multiple APis to that cloudfront distribution

Comment: Ah yes, this is maybe a key difference between what you are doing and what I do. Each pattern path is linked to a a different origin url where you are trying it with the same origin url.

Comment: if you do get it working; don't forget to enable query string forwarding as it does not automatically forwards ?q= for example which you might need on some of your API routes! :)